# Where does spring force come from?

Tags: spring

So we are studying about springs, as of noe, the assumption is that they are massless.

My teacher told me that when we extend a spring, or compress it, there is a force called the spring force which tries to reform the spring back it its original form. This force acts inwards and outwards respectively.

He also told us that the magnitude of this force is equal to the force we apply.

What I want to ask it, where does this force comes from? Why it it that the spring wants to retain its original form?

Comment: http://scienceline.ucsb.edu/getkey.php?key=343 is one source that answers this, but try this first https://www.quora.com/Why-do-springs-return-to-their-original-shape-after-being-deformed

Comment: thanks!! The quora one really helped! But what about plastic deformation? Why doesnt the body get back to its original shape after that? Doesnt it want to go to the lowest energy state?

Comment: @MartianCactus These questions are really covered in any introductory materials or mechanics of materials textbook.  The short answer is that once you get into the "plastic deformation" region, you begin changing the connections of the molecular structure; therefore changing the orientation of the low energy state.

Comment: Also something interesting about helical coil springs; it's actually like taking a big long bar and _twisting_ it.  That's what brings the coils closer.

Comment: so they are essentially springs that absorb energy? Also I would really appreciate if you would answer my other question about springs..

Comment: that absorb shock energy*